# VirtualBox doesn't load after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

After upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04, virtual box stopped working.

I've run the following to try to fix it:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install dkms
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

but when i run the last command I get:

```
bash: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: No such file or directory
```

When I try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/virtualbox start
```

I get:

```
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
 * No suitable module for running kernel found
```

I've also tried:

```
sudo dkms install virtualbox/4.1.2
```

and got:

```
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/virtualbox-4.1.2 does not exist.
```

I've also tried installing linux headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

but they were already installed.

From what I've read re-installing may not fix the problem. Is there a way I can fix virtual box?

Comment: lacking the 10 reputation to place an answer ... but shorthand is: ´apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms´ - one just needs to have build-essential and linux-headers installed previously.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling virtualbox using apt-get. It saw that there were kernel parts missing and installed them.

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Comment: Note that "sudo apt-get install virtualbox --reinstall" does not kick off the module build process.

Answer (score 36):

I had a similar problem.  Here is what worked for me:

This may be required if you get a kernel sources not found type of error:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Then reconfigure the relevant packages to kick them in to rebuilding.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox
```

Comment: That worked for me (with the modprobe as in GTO69's answer)

Comment: `apt-get install build-essential linux-headers\`uname -r\`` may also be needed, as a note.

Comment: I am getting `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
dpkg-query: package 'virtualbox-dkms' is not installed and no information is available` when I try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms`. I don't have this error after reinstalling virtualbox...

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me too:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

However, I had to add:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on @curtis's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/130076/97755), apparenly the answer's version specific

> You are using the wrong version for building the dkms. Try this:
>
> `sudo dkms install virtualbox/4.1.12`
>
> It appears to have worked for me. This is after you install the virtualbox-dkms package of course.

the **version** can be changed (in bold given in the quotation).

So try:

```
ls -d /usr/src/virtualbox*
```

which will give you something like

`/usr/src/virtualbox-version`

now take *version* and use it in the command above like

`sudo dkms install virtualbox/version`

If that is not giving you

> Module virtualbox/*version* already installed on kernel *kernelVersion*-generic/*architecture*

run this following commands after that(taken from other answers on the post)

- [rebuilding](https://askubuntu.com/a/126349/97755) just the kernel modules

  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms`
- [reinstalling](https://askubuntu.com/a/128130/97755)

  `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox && sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

and if required, load the module `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`

if DKMS is showing error that some kernel is missing, then just install the kernel and then rebuild/reinstall virtualbox.

**EDIT**: apparently this is also exist on 12.10

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong version for building the dkms. Try this:

```
sudo dkms install virtualbox/4.1.12
```

It appears to have worked for me. This is after you install the virtualbox-dkms package of course.

Answer (score 0):

I have same Problem, and in the Logfile

DKMS make.log for virtualbox-4.1.12 for kernel 3.8.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Mo 7. Okt 14:43:01 CEST 2013
make: Gehe in Verzeichnis '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/initterm-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In Funktion »rtR0MemObjNativeMapUser«:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1451:38: Fehler: »VM_RESERVED« nicht deklariert (erste Benutzung in dieser Funktion)
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1451:38: Anmerkung: jeder nicht deklarierte Bezeichner wird nur einmal für jede Funktion, in der er vorkommt, gemeldet
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o] Fehler 1
make[1]:**  [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv] Fehler 2
make: ** [*module*/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build] Fehler 2
make: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic'

what can i do?

3.8.0-31-generic

micha@Aspire-V3-771:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms[sudo] password for micha:

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 4.1.12

### Kernel:  3.5.0-18-generic (x86_64)

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.5.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.5.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.5.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

vboxpci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.5.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

---

Deleting module version: 4.1.12

### completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.
Loading new virtualbox-4.1.12 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.8.0-31-generic
Building initial module for 3.8.0-31-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/make.log for more information.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                            * No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
micha@Aspire-V3-771:~$

Comment: i have now install Virtualbox from http://www.virtualbox.org/
And now it's running ...:)