# How can I make Oracle VirtualBox appear in 12.04 dash?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

After upgrading to 12.04 I discovered I had the OSE version of VirtualBox, rather than the Oracle version previously installed. [I had to reinstall `virtualbox` it to get it working.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126175/virtualbox-doesnt-load-after-12-04-upgrade) Then, I re-enabled the Oracle repo and intalled `virtualbox-1.4`. However, while the OSE version came up in the dash, the Oracle version doesn't. It did when running under 11.10. Is this a bug? How can I make it appear in the dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling `virtualbox-4.1` resolved the issue. VirtualBox now appears in the dash and runs as expected.