# Win 7 Virtual Box VM fails to start after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, windows-7

I upgraded my Ubuntu OS on my laptop from 11.10 to 12.04,
I did the Virtual Box work arounds mentioned in the thread: [VirtualBox doesn't load after 12.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126175/virtualbox-doesnt-load-after-12-04-upgrade), 
My Turnkey Linux VM's are back up and running now however my windows 7 VM has failed to come up. My whole laptop freezes and i have to force restart my laptop each time I try to start my windows 7 VM.

Is there a work around to ensure smooth startup and running of win 7 VM's

My virtual box version is 4.1.12_Ubuntu r77245

Comment: the link was http://askubuntu.com/questions/126175/virtualbox-doesnt-load-after-12-04-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

The probably-related VirtualBox bug ticket says it is fixed in VirtualBox source, and also details a workaround via grub.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10528

Hopefully the patch will be applied to Ubuntu-12.04 .

Comment: The Debian bug is:
[http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=655202](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=655202)

Answer (score 0):

What are your Ubuntu and Windows versions (including 32 bit or 64 bit)?

I also had some problems when setting up VirtualBox 64 bit Windows machine on 32 bit Ubuntu, but everything works fine with 32 bit Windows.

Comment: The Windows I have is 64bit and the host ubuntu is 32. The same setup was there in 11.10 and things worked just fine. After I upgraded to 12.04 this issue is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; 64bit version of Windows 7 machine on 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04. failing to startup with Virtualbox 4.1.14

This setup worked perfectly until I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04

Removing and reinstall Virtualbox did not solve the problem:

```
    sudo apt-get remove Virtualbox-4.1
    sudo apt-get install Virtualbox-4.1
```

ALSO executing:

```
    sudo aptitude update
    sudo aptitude install dkms
    sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

At last I created a 32bit version of Windows 7 machine and it works with fine without any problems.